# Need help setting up passenger with apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, fedora

I'm trying to setup passenger with apache on Fedora 14. The install went ok but I'm unable to configure apache correctly.
I made these changes to the file. I cannot start apache unless I comment out the virtual host portion.

> LoadModule passenger_module
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
>   PassengerRoot
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7
>   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>    
     ServerName localhost    
 DocumentRoot  /home/antarr/pull/public      
     <Directory /home/antarr/pull/public>
            AllowOverride all      
            Options -MultiViews      
      </Directory>  
      </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need the following two lines in your apache2.conf or in a conditionally loaded, module specific conf file:

```
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Make sure you correct the paths so they are correct to your specific configuration. From what you have in your question, it looks like you would need to remove "/local" from what I pasted above.

Comment: I've already done that but mine is 1.8, and when I go to those folders they are actually empty

Comment: Have you run "passenger-install-apache2-module"? At the end, that will give you the exact lines you need to add for your configuration.

Comment: type `which ruby` to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying `httpd-vhosts.conf` override `DocumentRoot` in your httpd.conf

```
# Override default DocumentRoot with you root
DocumentRoot "/home/antarr/pull/public"
<Directory "/home/antarr/pull/public">
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Before restarting server make sure your conf change is reflected

```
apachectl -S
```

The Document root should point to your root folder. And restart apache.